# How to show just the rectangles in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I was given this function:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

from skimage.measure import regionprops

import math

facteurforme = lambda r: (4 * math.pi * r.area) / (r.perimeter * r.perimeter)

circ = lambda r: (r.perimeter)/(r.equivalent_diameter)
```

I should complete the code to detect just the rectangles in image made of circles and rectangles and then put the detected shapes in a box using `Python 3`.

I'd know how to use `facteurforme`.

Help please!.

Comment: Are you asking what `facteurforme` means? Are you asking how to distinguish circles from rectangles? Are you asking how to measure area and perimeter? Are you asking how to put a box around detections? Are you asking someone to complete the whole exercise for you? Please be explicit about it! Show what you’ve tried so far, to limit the scope of the question. See [ask] for how to ask questions that attract good answers.

Answer (score 2):

`facteurforme` is a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

> Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create
>   anonymous functions. The expression lambda parameters: expression
>   yields a function object. The unnamed object behaves like a function
>   object defined with:
>
> `def <lambda>(parameters):
>       return expression`

As you're supposed to use [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops) and `facteurforme` uses `r.area` and `r.perimeter` which are properties of regionprops it is obvious that you should use a set of region properties as the lambda's argument.

facteureforme calculates the [isoperimetric quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) for a given set of region properties.

This quotient is only 1 for a circle (or very close to 1 in a non-theoretical case) and less for anything else. You can use this value to distinguish between circles and rectangles.

Also see [Shape Factor: Circularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy))

`r.equivalent_diameter` should be renamed `r.equivalent_diameterfloat` btw.

To get started with your homework I suggest you search the web for regionprops tutorials / examples